# How do I disable the export menu in amCharts

Tags: javascript, user-interface, amcharts4

For one of our charts, we load it in batches, which could take a while. We'd like to disable the export menu (i.e., not allow it to open when the user clicks it) while the batches are loaded and enable it again once the last batch is in the chart. How does one go about doing that? Ideally, some indication that it's disabled (e.g., dimming, grey text) would also be nice to have.

For further info, the code for creating the menu is something along these lines:

```
chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
chart.exporting.menu.items = [
  {
    label: "...",
    menu: [
      {
        type: "custom",
        label: "CSV",
        title: "Download CSV,
        options:
          {
            callback: function()
              {
                // function for downloading CSV data
              }
          }
      }]
  }];
if (needPrintOption)
  {
    chart.exporting.menu.items[0].menu.push(
      {
        label: "Print",
        title: "Print Chart",
        type: "custom",
        options:
          {
            callback: function()
              {
                // function to print chart contents
              }
          }
      });
  }
```

The menu is created when the chart is created. Essentially, I want the top level (labeled "...") to be disabled (ideally with some visual indication) while the chart is loading or being updated. (I don't want to have to create and destroy the menu, as we do have a live mode where the data in the chart is added to periodically. It would be less jarring for the user, visually, to disable the menu when I don't want user interaction with it and re-enable it when user interaction is allowed.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ready` event:

```
chart.events.on('ready', () => {
  chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
});
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't this code simply replace the existing menu with a blank one? That's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to disable the existing menu. (I want to the menu to always be there, but disable it any time the chart is loaded or updated with new data.)

Comment: you place your code inside, how can I know your menu code?